# Why it is nearly impossible to have an approximation algorithm for Maximum Clique problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, approximation

I read a theorem which states that:
If there exists a polynomial time approximation algorithm for solving the Maximum Clique problem (or the Maximum Independent Set problem) for any constant performance ratio r, then NP = P.

But I never understood the reasoning behind this!!

Comment: What research have you done? Where have you looked? You might take a look at [the Wikipedia page on the clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Hardness_of_approximation), which has some pointers to where you can find more. It looks like the results follow from results on PCP, which are non-trivial.  I don't know if there's a more elementary proof.

Comment: plz cite the thm!

Comment: update: this article(https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.04396) claimed a 2-approximation algorithm for MAX-CLIQUE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, something stronger is true: if you can approximate maximum clique within $n^{1-\epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ then P=NP. This is because for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a polytime reduction $f_\epsilon$ that takes an instance $\varphi$ of SAT and returns an instance $(G,cn)$ of maximum clique such that:

1. If $\varphi$ is satisfiable then $G$ has a $cn$-clique.
2. If $\varphi$ is not satisfiable then $G$ has no $cn^{1-\epsilon}$-clique.

If you could approximate maximum clique within $n^{1-\epsilon}$ you would be able to distinguish the two cases (exercise), and so to decide whether $\varphi$ is satisfiable or not.

The reduction uses the PCP theorem as a first ingredient. Given the PCP theorem it is not hard to give a similar reduction with a constant gap, and with some effort to give a reduction with a gap of $n^\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. The reduction claimed above, which has a gap of $n^{1-\epsilon}$ for every $\epsilon>0$, is much harder. See [lecture notes of Guruswami and O'Donnell](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse533/05au/lecture10.pdf) for the constant gap, and [lecture notes of Scheideler](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~scheideler/courses/600.471_S05/lecture_9.pdf) for the $n^\epsilon$ gap.

Comment: What insight does this give me on the decision version of the problem.? Just curious...

Comment: @ARi It implies it's NP-hard.